# How do I limit query results, when distinct isn't distinct?

Tags: ssms-2014

I have a bill of material file that I am trying to reduce to only the unique parts, and related data for the line.  The problem I'm running into is multiple instances of a part number due to variations in the formatting or language in the part name from the system/s that a third party pulls the data from.
pn123  part_name
pn123  Part-name
pn123  Part name
pn123  German name

All other fields I select are equal, how do I limit this in the where clause to just one instance of the above for all different part numbers?  Is there an equivalent to MAX() in a text string?

I am working around the issue in excel, by deleting the dupes.

```
select distinct

adhoc.ats_esh.Customs_Entry_Num
[VIN]as [Qlickview VIN]
,[Build_Date]
,[BOM_Level]
,[9802].[Supplier]
,[Part_number]
,[Part_Name] *******THIS IS THE PROBLEM FIELD*******
,[Unit_Price]
,[Usage]
,[Extended_Price]

from 


adhoc.IMFM_9802_EU_AP [9802] inner join ADHOC.ATS_ESL
    ON [9802].VIN = ADHOC.ATS_ESL.Part_Num
        inner join adhoc.ATS_ESH
    ON ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Trans_SK = ADHOC.ATS_ESL.Trans_SK



    where

adhoc.ats_esh.importer ='ACME_CO'
and adhoc.ATS_ESH.ENTRY_SUMMARY_DATE >= '2/01/2018'
And adhoc.ATS_ESH.ENTRY_SUMMARY_DATE < '3/01/2018'
AND adhoc.ats_esl.Supplier in('supplier1','supplier2','supplier3')

--and adhoc.ats_esl.Part_Num like '%ABC%'

--and [BOM_Level] = '1' --**** use MAX()
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to have a table with part name and number where part number is a unique key. This way you join on Part_number and get a unique Part_name. You can also use **Max(Part_name)** if you use **Group by Part_number** but this will require you to rework your query a little bit.